# Representation of translation group on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am having the following question:

If we consider the group $G_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that acts on a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, by $g_{\alpha}x = (x_{1}+a_{1}, ..., x_{n}+a_{n})$, is there some way of getting a representation for an element $g_{\alpha}$ that is given by a matrix?

Is this possible if we restrict to $\alpha$ being one-dimensional, i.e. the action is $g_{\alpha}x = (x_{1}+a, ..., x_{n}+a)$ of a further restriction that $G$ is finite, i.e. we only pick a finite number of real numbers for $\alpha$.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is linear. That is, for every $n\times n$ matrix $A$ the map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ given by $x\mapsto Ax$ is a linear map. All the maps $x\mapsto x+\alpha$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb R^n$ are non-linear, with the obvious exception for $\alpha=0$ — they are translations.

Hence, you can't describe those translations by a matrix in the standard meaning of "description by a matrix".

However, by embedding $\mathbb R^n$ into the projective space $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ (using homogeneous coordinates), you can indeed describe translation by matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & a_{n-1}\\
\vdots & & \ddots & 1 & a_n \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} x_1+a_1\\\vdots\\x_n+a_n\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.